# Proper English for programmer-dependent

Tags: idioms

I'm Japanese and there is a JP word 'programmer-dependent' which means something relies on human, not the system. Does anybody know how to say that in English?

e.g. Memory management of C is 'programmer-dependent', and that of Python is not (because of GC).

I've searched the word in web, but I found nothing. Thanks.

Comment: The typical phrasing is *manual* vs *automatic*.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with *programmer dependant*. I don't think anybody would think a programmer *wasn't* a human . . .

Comment: I agree with @Jason. I personally would have no problem referring to memory management in C or C++ as being "programmer-dependent."

Answer (score 2):

Online you will see both **manual** and **explicit** used for functionality like memory management that must be written by the programmer, e.g.

> In computer science, **manual** memory management refers to the usage of manual instructions by the programmer to identify and deallocate unused objects, or garbage. 
>   - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_memory_management

and

> comparison of garbage collection to **explicit** memory management in a garbage-collected language ...
>   - https://people.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/04-17.pdf

Comment: This is a good response as it's accurate not only for the specific example, but also as a general idiom.  "Manual" = "depending on human action"; "Automatic" = "happening without human action"